# アセンブリでidivlを実行

Tags: assembly

これを実行したところ、予想では`-21`になると思っていたのですが、実際には`75350281`という値が表示されました。色々と調べたのですが原因がわからず詰まっています。誰かお力添え願えませんか。

```
.data
L_fmt:
    .ascii "%d\n\0"
.text
.globl _main
_main:
    pushl %ebp
    movl  %esp, %ebp
    movl  $0, %eax
    movl  $0, %ebx
    movl  $0, %ecx
    movl  $0, %edx
    movl  $1, %ebx
    imull  $10, %ebx
    addl  $2, %ebx
    imull  $10, %ebx
    addl  $3, %ebx
    imull  $10, %ebx
    addl  $4, %ebx
    negl  %ebx
    addl  %ebx, %eax
    movl  $5, %ebx
    imull  $10, %ebx
    addl  $7, %ebx
    idivl  %ebx
    pushl %eax
    pushl $L_fmt
    call  _printf
    addl  $16, %esp
    leave
    ret
```

Comment: `idivl %ebx` とした場合、実際には `%edx:%eax` の 64 ビット長で表される整数値を `%ebx` の値で除算する事になります。つまり、`4294966062 / 57` が実行されて、`%eax` に `75350281` がセットされる事になります(`%edx` には剰余である `45` がセットされます)。

Comment: というわけですので、`movl $0, %edx` の代わりに `movl $-1, %edx` とすればよろしいかと思います。

Comment: @metropolis さん、それだと%eaxの正負がわかっている場合にしか使えません。%eax / %ebx の符号付き除算を行いたいならidivの前にcdqを置いて符号拡張するのが常道でしょう。

Comment: @OOPer なるほど、それは知りませんでした。ありがとうございます。